# Adding dictonary into the dictonary using 'for' loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Below are the lists :

```
text = ['is', 'ramping', 'brings']
head = ['ramping', 'ramping', 'ramping']
childWord = [[],
 ['Cola', 'is', 'up', 'launches', 'brings', 'drink', '.'],
 ['as', 'it', 'mineral']]
```

And using below code I am updating this list item in value of dictonary verb.

```
verb = {}
for i in range(0 , len(text)):

    verb [i] = {'Verb Text': text[i], 'Text Head of the verb' : head[i], 'Child Word of the verb' : childWord[i]}

verb.update(verb [i])
verb
```

And I am getting an output as follow:

```
{0: {'Verb Text': 'is',
  'Text Head of the verb': 'ramping',
  'Child Word of the verb': []},
 1: {'Verb Text': 'ramping',
  'Text Head of the verb': 'ramping',
  'Child Word of the verb': ['Cola',
   'is',
   'up',
   'launches',
   'brings',
   'drink',
   '.']},
 2: {'Verb Text': 'brings',
  'Text Head of the verb': 'ramping',
  'Child Word of the verb': ['as', 'it', 'mineral']},
 'Verb Text': 'brings',
 'Text Head of the verb': 'ramping',
 'Child Word of the verb': ['as', 'it', 'mineral']}
```

In the output the issue is its creating below key value pair two times

```
'Verb Text': 'brings',
 'Text Head of the verb': 'ramping',
 'Child Word of the verb': ['as', 'it', 'mineral']
```

Any comments will be appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `verb.update(verb[i])` updates the dictionary with the last element after the for loop, hence the last element comes up twice.

Remove that line and your code will work fine

Hence the code changes to

```
text = ['is', 'ramping', 'brings']
head = ['ramping', 'ramping', 'ramping']
childWord = [[],
 ['Cola', 'is', 'up', 'launches', 'brings', 'drink', '.'],
 ['as', 'it', 'mineral']]

verb = {}
for i in range(0 , len(text)):

    verb [i] = {'Verb Text': text[i], 'Text Head of the verb' : head[i], 'Child Word of the verb' : childWord[i]}

#Remove this line since it is updating the dictionary with the last element again
#verb.update(verb [i])

print(verb)
```

You can also simplify the code by restructuing your dictionary and then using list comprehension to calculate your final list

```
#Dictionary of keys to list of values
dct = { 'Verb Text': ['is', 'ramping', 'brings'],
'Text Head of the verb': ['ramping', 'ramping', 'ramping'],
'Child Word of the verb': [[],
 ['Cola', 'is', 'up', 'launches', 'brings', 'drink', '.'],
 ['as', 'it', 'mineral']]

}

#Keys of the dictionary
keys = dct.keys()

#Iterate over the indexes and keys to make your list via list and dictionary comprehension
verb =  [{key:dct[key][idx]} for idx in range(len(dct['Verb Text'])) for key in keys]

print(verb)
```

And the output will be same in both cases which is

```
{
0: {'Verb Text': 'is', 'Text Head of the verb': 'ramping', 'Child Word of the verb': []}, 
1: {'Verb Text': 'ramping', 'Text Head of the verb': 'ramping', 'Child Word of the verb': ['Cola', 'is', 'up', 'launches', 'brings', 'drink', '.']}, 
2: {'Verb Text': 'brings', 'Text Head of the verb': 'ramping', 'Child Word of the verb': ['as', 'it', 'mineral']}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the dictionary at the end outside the loop and that caused duplication of the last value. Remove the `dict.update` outside loop:

```
verb = {}
for i in range(0 , len(text)):
    verb[i] = {'Verb Text': text[i], 'Text Head of the verb' : head[i], 'Child Word of the verb' : childWord[i]}

#verb.update(verb [i])  <- Remove this line

print(verb)
```

A better way would be using the built-in `zip` and `enumerate` like:

```
verb = {} 
for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(zip(text, head, childWord)):
    verb[i] =  {'Verb Text': x, 'Text Head of the verb': y, 'Child Word of the verb': z}

print(verb)
```

which again using dictionary-comprehension:

```
verb = {i: {'Verb Text': x, 'Text Head of the verb': y, 'Child Word of the verb': z} for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(zip(text, head, childWord))}
```

Comment: Thank you Austin for you quick response !!